# How to make a function restart depend on answer(Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from random import randint
def roll_the_dice():
    dice = randint(1, 6)
    dice2 = randint(1, 6)
    print dice , dice2
    x = raw_input('If you want to reroll press 1 if not press 2:\n')
    if x == int(1):
        continue
    elif x == int(2):
        break
    else:
        print 'Invalid input'

roll_the_dice()
```

The problem is where i put the continue , how do i make it restart depend on the answer

Comment: Use a `while` loop? `break` and `continue` don't make much sense without loops

Comment: You could call roll_the_dice() instead of continue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: i tried it now its not working i think you cant use the function you defining inside it

Comment: You'd be better off using a while loop. Using recursion for input validatation like this is a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to run until a specific case, you can put it inside a *while true* loop. When using break and continue, it's in context of a loop. It could be a *for* loop or any kind of loop, but if you want the loop to run forever (Or until you break it) you can use *while true*.

Like this:

```
from random import randint

def roll_the_dice():
    while True:
        dice = randint(1, 6)
        dice2 = randint(1, 6)
        print dice , dice2
        x = raw_input('If you want to reroll press 1 if not press 2:\n')
        if x == int(1):
            continue
        elif x == int(2):
            break
        else:
            print 'Invalid input'

roll_the_dice()
```

Comment: can you put an examlpe?

Comment: Added an example, but note that it will reroll on invalid input.